# pandas.read_json gives ValueError: Unrecognized escape sequence when decoding 'string' for a huge data set

Tags: json, pandas

While using `pd.read_json` on a huge data set (1.26GB) I get an error saying `ValueError: Unrecognized escape sequence when decoding 'string'`
Since it's not possible to change every escape sequence, how do I parse this file into json?

It's causing an error on this line
`{"text": "I'm always looking for a good Eggs Benny.  This usually leads me to major hotel restaurants, but you can always find a good representation at a smaller independent restaurant.\n\nSteve's is a spacious restaurant just south of the 407, and worth a quick detour to get a well executed b,
reakfast. Nicely poached eggs, a tasty chunk of pea meal bacon on an English muffin, smothered in Hollandaise.  With a generous portion of home fries, it's a meal that carries me through most of the day.\n\nEggs Benedict: that's what I came for and it was worth the short deviation.  Become a deviant yourself!", "id": 81164}`

Comment: Could you a sample of the data? It might the fact there would be single quote`'` rather than double `"` to represent strings in json file. Can't say anything without looking at sample data

Comment: Is there a way to print out the json line causing the error? That would be useful. Maybe using some other module?

Comment: Found the line causing the error. But there might be more.

Answer (score 1):

I was splitting the whole file into smaller files and appending them together. A newline was introduced while doing this which made the above error happen.